# convert a list[str] to list[int] in python

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import os
from typing import Mapping

from colorama import Fore , init

init()

os.system("cls" or "clear")

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
#GIVE A NUMBER
num = int(input(Fore.GREEN+"Please Enter A Number: "))
#GIVE A LIST NUMBER
listed = input(Fore.GREEN+"Please Enter A List Of Number: ")
# CONVERT INPUT(STR) TO LIST:
listed = [listed]
#CONVERT LIST(STR) TO LIST(INT)
listed= list(map(int, listed))
#APPEND NUMBER TO LIST:
listed.append(num)
#SORT LIST
listed = listed.sort()
#PRINT LIST
print(Fore.RED+listed)
```

and i got these error:
Please Enter A Number: 12

Please Enter A List Of Number: 12,35,25

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\roya\1.py", line 14, in

listed= list(map(int, listed))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12,35,25'

What should i do to convert all number is in input to int????

Comment: Side-note: `os.system("cls" or "clear")` only works on Windows. `"cls" or "clear"` *always* evaluates to `"cls"`. You need to actually test the platform to determine which one to use if you want it to be portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also an error in your last line. Here's the whole thing corrected:

```
import os
from typing import Mapping

from colorama import Fore , init

init()

os.system("cls" or "clear")

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
#GIVE A NUMBER
num = int(input(Fore.GREEN+"Please Enter A Number: "))
#GIVE A LIST NUMBER
listed = input(Fore.GREEN+"Please Enter A List Of Number: ")
# CONVERT INPUT(STR) TO LIST:
listed = listed.split(',')
print(listed)
#CONVERT LIST(STR) TO LIST(INT)
listed= list(map(int, listed))
#APPEND NUMBER TO LIST:
listed.append(num)
#SORT LIST
listed = listed.sort()
#PRINT LIST
print(Fore.RED+str(listed))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
listed = [listed]
```

This creates a single-element list with the variable `listed`. It does not split the string into multiple ones.

To do that you need to do:

```
listed = listed.split(',')
```

Which should create the list `['12', '35', '25']` - which would be a valid input to `list(map(int, listed))`

Comment: 'print(Fore.RED+str(listed))' for last line and what you siad i mixed i got answer

Answer (score 1):

this would do

```py
listed = list(map(int, listed.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can user regex expression and capture spaces when entering inputs and then convert to list from int:

```
import re
listed = re.split(r"\s", listed)
listed = [int(item) for item in listed]
```